# How should I word my question and where is the best place to ask it?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, site-recommendation

I tried asking this question on Stack overflow, but it was immediately rejected:

> I'm trying to redevelop a mobile website written in classic ASP so we
>   can integrate it into a mobile app, but still keep it functional on
>   the web. The app has its own menu, and displays the mobile site in a
>   nested browser, so it's redundant to leave the menu on the mobile
>   site.
>
> Basically we want the site to show in the app without the menu, and
>   use the app's menu instead, but still be functional in a browser.
>
> I need help just finding an angle to approach this problem, discover
>   what my options are, but I'm not sure how to ask the question without
>   it sounding subjective.

Comment: Rejected in what sense exactly?

Comment: @MrLore but I can't find such questions or see them listed in users profile. Also, if he means rejected by the quality filter it means it wasn't yet posted.

Comment: In my original question I asked about an alternative to frames applied to my circumstance, but my question was swiftly marked as a duplicate. I tried to rephrase the question, but finally just ended up deleting it, that's when I started to search for a better place to ask it.

Answer (score 5):

That question is too broad for StackOverflow, as there is no "[specific programming problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)".

I see [you've also posted it on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/251046/integrating-a-mobile-website-into-a-mobile-app), where it does seem to be on-topic as it's about [software architecture and design](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Yes, I just got a response on Programmers and it does look like I finally managed to ask the right question in the right place.